# Check checkbox if comma separated values exists in php mysql

Tags: php, checkbox

first of all sorry for my bad english :) i have a table named members, and in a row there are language values which are comma separated. while user edits his/her profile i want language checkbox checked if value exists in table. i tried this but only the last checkbox is checked.

```
$langs = explode(", ", $p['lang']);

<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" <? if (in_array('English', $langs)) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />English

<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Spanish" <? if (in_array('Spanish', $langs)) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />Spanish
```

Comment: This will work if your string is "English, Spanish". What is the string?

Comment: Are you sure you're `explode` is giving what you want? If your string is "English , Spanish" (note the spaces) your test will fail as "English " != "English" (again, note spaces).

Comment: string is "English, Spanish". i tried like "English , Spanish" and changed explode(" , ", ...) but it was the same problem...

Comment: if you really have `"English , Spanish"` in you string, will get `true` both times comparing it with `English` and than with `Spanish` (don't forget ot use [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$langs = array_map('trim', explode(",", $p['lang']));
<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Spanish" <?=(in_array('Spanish', $langs)?'checked="checked"':NULL)?> />Spanish
```

EDIT explanation: first line will delete leading and trailing whitespaces from all elements, and the second line you have to repeat for all you languages

`true/false ? statement for true : statement for false` is used there to `check` your boxes

trim solution found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#104176)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$p['lang'] = 'English,Spanish';

$langs = explode(",", $p['lang']);

function checkboxChecked($input)
{
    global $langs;

    if (in_array($input, $langs))
    {
        return 'checked';
    }
}

<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" <?php checkboxChecked('English'); ?> />English

<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Spanish" <?php checkboxChecked('Spanish'); ?> />Spanish
```

** It may need an echo before the function like this :

```
<?php echo checkboxChecked('Spanish'); ?>
```

If this doesnt work try this (after the explode) and copy/paste the result in comments

```
print_f($langs);
```

Comment: global variables? seems to be bad solution

Comment: because it's a [bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).  I don't have enough space here to explain you all issues with security, namespaces, etc. you can create question on stackoverflow about it. @zPuls3

Comment: @vladkras i think u r wrong, the global command in a function means that this variable can be accessed in this function.

Comment: I know what it means, create queation and I'll be glad to answer it @zPuls3

Answer (score 0):

you must try this,
this is bit lengthy but works great

```
Present<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" <?php $result=mysql_query("select date from student where no='$_POST[rollno]'"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ if ($row['date']=='2015-08-10') {echo 'checked="checked"';}} ?> />
```

Comment: Does not look lengthy at all ;) Could you format your code, please?!